# Cannot format duration in Google Sheets as HH:MM, it's ALWAYS HH.MM.SS?

Tags: google-sheets

I've spent hours trying to format Duration as HH:MM in Google Sheets.

The formatting seems OK at first. But when I then enter "13:00" for instance, I get an error, but when I enter "13.00.00" it's fine.

Now, what is it that makes this so hard to get working as "expected"?

And by "expected" I mean; when I format a cell to display like "HH:MM" (13:00), I would expect to be able to enter values in exactly that format, and not any other ("13.00.00").

Answer (score 0):

enter **custom date and time formats** under **<kbd>123</kbd>** button and set up your desired format:

[image: 0]

Comment: No, the problem is that I CANNOT key in 13:00 even though the cell is formatted that way – I HAVE to type 13.00.00 (a completely different format), otherwise I get a #VALUE error for the cell using the value for calculations. Neither h:mm or hh:mm is changing the format for input.

A weird thing I noticed was that when revisitting the custom format is't changed to hh":"mm ... with these quotation marks around the semicolon. Don't know what that is).

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu item `Format` > `Number` > `More Formats` > `Custom number format...` Type in `[h]:mm` or `[hh]:mm` (if you want a leading zero when appropriate).

You're right about inconsistency. If you key in 13:00 you're okay. But if you try to shorthand it to 13 and expect 13:00 it doesn't work. Then if you try to key 13:00 back in it will appear okay in the cell but the formula bar will now reflect time (1:00:00 PM) instead of duration (13:00:00.000) at which point you'd have to reformat the cell.